# Android Different Resolution Support in IBM Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am searching on different resolution support in IBM Worklight android . From this side i am reading tutorials [IBM Worklight Tutorials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#mobile-client-development) In tutorial/module 09 they discuss about different resolutions. 
In the document there is line which telling:

> By default, Android application assumes that the application HTML
>   file was styled for a screen width of 320 pixels.
>    When displaying graphical elements on wider screens, Android
>   automatically scales images and fonts to the appropriate ratio.
>    For example, on a 480-pixel wide screen, a 100-pixel wide image will
>   be scaled by 480/320 (= 1.5) to 150 pixels in width

Now i make a Worklight Hybrid project and set a background image in it and two buttons on this image. Its a demo app in which i am testing different resolutions.

Now i deploy this app in android and run it on Tab 7 inch ,nexus 4 and tab 10.1 .Now my image size is 580x320 and bit depth is 24.

When i run this project on nexus 4 it gives the width of image correct but it do not scales the image height vise.

When i run this project on tab 7 2 , it shows the image having some extra white space on the left of image and extra white space on height of image means down the image.

When i run on tab 10.1 it shows the same behavior as the tab 7 2 did.

I am really confuse that which exact general size will be use so that all these scale on all screen sizes and not shows extra white space on width and on height

Comment: Add targetSdkVersion to <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> in  AndroidManifest.xml, its value would be from 13 upwards, this should change the resolution of the content displayed on screen in Android 4 and up.

Comment: thank you for the response. But i don't understand because <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> its already added in manifest file. So i think its not related to sdk version

Comment: targetSdkVersion is another property to add to the uses-sdk tag. It indicates against which Android SDK to compile your code, which also controls things like UI widgets and resolution.

Comment: any solution regarding IBM workligt because its give development in javascript and html

Comment: It is Android that controls these type of things, not Worklight. Using Worklight, you create the app, but which platform versions you target in Android is up for you to setup in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: but i am asking about layouts .because it gives html file to develop app for different resolutions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26023/discussion-between-user95280-and-idan-adar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Worklight Skins](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_developing_application_skins.html) in order to support multiple Android devices (with varying screen sizes) in your application.

Comment: ok thankyou. I got that link and work on it crate my own skin and try to run that on tab 2 7 but the problem exist still why it showing me the image in zoom mode. And if try to resize the image smaller than the device resolution and run this app again than image get in center and shows white space on left of image and on bottom

Answer (score 0):

Idan's answer works for me.  I have a android tablet for some reason the app looks very blurry and huge buttons and fonts all the time.  I have tried all the different target-densitydpi setting, the button might have change sizes.  But everything is still very blurry.

Then I set this in the Android manifest as per Idan.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
```

Now everything is sharp and crisp on my low resolution tablet.  It turns out that Android would automatically do some scaling "screen compatibility mode" even though my device can support better resolution.  Android will still treat this as low resolution and scale things automatically.  By providing the target, it will stop this behaviour when the device is higher than that Android version.  Read more here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Note, though, that this may cause crash on orientation change. This is better handled in Worklight v5.0.6.1.